# Buffer control when using gdb under emacs

Tags: emacs, gdb, frames

I am using gdb under emacs. During a debug session, when emacs/gdb jumps to source code i usually open up another frame (C-x 5 2) and pull that onto my second monitor.
The problem comes when a new source code file needs to be opened (for example when the program enters a function defined in another source file, walking the stack, etc ...) emacs tends to automatically open up the corresponding source code in a new window, but unfortunately in the gdb frame.

I would like for it pull up new source code in the new frame i opened up and leave the gdb frame completely untouched. My question then is this:

How can i set emacs to open up any new file such that the file is displayed in the new frame?

I hope i am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple answer, but an appropriate entry in display-buffer-alist could tell display-buffer to always use the frame you want as the destination for new buffers.

In 24.1, the doc is:

> display-buffer-alist is a variable defined in `window.el'. Its value
>   is nil
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation: Alist of conditional actions for `display-buffer'. This
>   is a list of elements (CONDITION . ACTION), where:
>
> CONDITION is either a regexp matching buffer names, or a   function
>   that takes two arguments - a buffer name and the   ACTION argument of
>   `display-buffer' - and returns a boolean.
>
> ACTION is a cons cell (FUNCTION . ALIST), where FUNCTION is a
>   function or a list of functions.  Each such function should   accept
>   two arguments: a buffer to display and an alist of the   same form as
>   ALIST.  See `display-buffer' for details.
>
> `display-buffer' scans this alist until it either finds a matching
>   regular expression or the function specified by a condition returns
>   non-nil.  In any of these cases, it adds the associated action to the
>   list of actions it will try.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 24.1 of Emacs.